Hot water coming from cold water faucet
Why would there be hot water coming out of my cold water faucet? It is only hot for about 20-30 seconds.

How close is it to the hot water tank?  Often the tank will warm up the cold water line to the tank and that is why.

If you live in Arizona, that would be normal

A warm/hot summer years ago doing haying, had a similar problem.  Wanted cold water now without waiting.  A back flow preventer/check valve near the tank fixed it.

It's normal in Florida too.

We need more information.  Where in the world is your house?  Is your house air conditioned?  Does the cold water line run through the air conditioning?  If not, does it run through the attic?  Basement?  Exterior wall?  Is it on the interior side of any insulation?  How close is the cold water line to the hot?  Is there a mixing valve?  Pictures of the plumbing line might help make some of these determinations.
